how EVM/ETH Estimate gas work
i find there is no article about EVM estimate gas Working principle in stack over flow
thank you

You can check this ref:
https://github.com/wolflo/evm-opcodes/blob/main/gas.md
I think it's quite clear article

Thank you very much

For an accurate gas estimation wallets simulate the execution of the transaction, with data from current confirmed block.
If the data from intervening contracts doesn't change the transaction should cost the same amount of gas than the estimation. The final ether price may vary depending on the gas price.
